# Round up a Pandas Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of Pandas Timestamps with me. It is supposed to be 15 mints seperated, but due to some error in measurements there may be mistakes in minutes.

I want to round up the Timestamp to next nearest 15 minutes.

I know I can use `Timestamp.round()` from pandas to round the Timestamp. But the problem with it is it rounds to nearest 15 mints. I always want to round up to next 15 minutes.

For example,

If I have a timestamp as given below,

```
ts = pd.Timestamp('2017-12-31 23:50:00+0530')

rounded = ts.round(freq='15T')
```

The result I will get is `Timestamp('2017-12-31 23:45:00+0530', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(330)')`.

I dont want this to happen, I want the result to be next 15 minute timestamp ie it must be

```
Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00+0530', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(330)')
```

At the same time, I will have timestamps of the form

```
Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00+0530', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(330)')
```

If I am using `Timestamp.ceil` for my purpose, I will get an output like this

```
Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:15:00+0530', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(330)')
```

I don't want it to be happening.

The output must be

```
 Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00+0530', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(330)')
```

In short, If the time stamp is correct no cieling must be done and if the timestam is not at 15 mints it must be ceiled.

How can I do this with pandas easily.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think need `if-else`:

```
ts = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00+0530')

print (ts.ceil(freq='15T') if ts.strftime('%H:%M:%S') != '00:00:00' 
                           else ts)
2018-01-01 00:00:00+05:30

from datetime import time

print (ts.ceil(freq='15T') if ts.time() != time(0,0,0)  else ts)
2018-01-01 00:00:00+05:30
```

Comment: Good catch with the rounding up `00-00` timestamps

Comment: @user3483203 - Thank you. Btw, your regex perfect solutions I like very much ;)

Comment: @jezrael I think you didn't get me correctly. When the time is `pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00+0530')` it is correct and I dont want ceiling or rounding to happen in thos cases. the output must be `pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00+0530')`

Comment: Yep, I did it so. Thanks

Comment: But it is checking `00:00:00`. I also want rounding not happening in valid 15 mints timestamps. ie if the timestamps are 00:00:00 or 00:15:00 or 00:30:00 or 00:45:00 or xx:15:00 so on it must not be rounded.

Comment: If the timestamp is `pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 12:15:00')` It must be `pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 12:15:00')` not `pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 12:30:00')`

Comment: @SreeramTP - Maybe simplier is `ts.strftime('%H:%M:%S') != '00:00:00'` change to `ts.strftime('%H:%M:%S') not in ['00:00:00', '00:15:00',  '00:30:00',  '00:45:00']`, can you check it?

Comment: yeah, it must work. I was thinking whether there are anything different.

Comment: `['00:00:00', '00:15:00', '00:30:00', '00:45:00'] ` wont handle the situation. I may want to list all the hours in the same manner. I am looking something more elegant

Comment: @SreeramTP - OK, so give me some time.

Comment: I have handled it. I will post it as an answer

Comment: @SreeramTP - Just test it and for me working `print (ts.ceil(freq='15T'))` nice, what is your pandas version ?

Comment: Version is 0.23.0

Comment: @SreeramTP - My version is `pandas: 0.23.4`

Comment: I basically extended your solution, instead of checking ts is not 00:00:00 i made a list of all the 15mints timestamps with pandas date_range and stripped only hours and check ts not in that list

Answer (score 7):

You want `ceil`, not `round`:

```
ts.ceil(freq='15T')
```

```
Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00+0530', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(330)')
```

Comment: I wasn't knowing about this. Thanks

Comment: There is also a little catch. I will update the question for that

Answer (score 2):

```
 import pandas as pd

    ts = pd.Timestamp('2017-12-31 23:50:00+0530')
    ceil = ts.ceil(freq='15T')
    print(ceil)
```

> 2018-01-01 00:00:00+05:30

**Timestamp.ceil()** return a new Timestamp ceiled to this resolution , [link here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Timestamp.ceil.html#pandas.Timestamp.ceil)

**Timestamp.floor()** return a new Timestamp floored to this resolution, [link here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html#pandas.Timestamp.floor)

Answer (score 2):

The solution posted by @jazrael was awesome and it worked for the base case. It was also good so that I could be extended for every hour i wanted by provding a list of 15 minutes timestamps for each hour. It needed to list a 96 element and check it in the code shown below.

```
from datetime import time

ts = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00+0530')

print (ts.ceil(freq='15T') if ts.strftime('%H:%M:%S') != [list of 15 mints timestamps]
                           else ts)
```

I generated a list of needed hours and handled the checking like this.

```
from datetime import time, timedelta
import numpy

ts = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 12:15:00')

print(ts.ceil(freq='15T') if ts.strftime('%H:%M:%S') not in [x.strftime('%H:%M:%S') for x in pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'), end=pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 23:45:00'), freq='15T')]
      else ts)
```